# What's the difference between prod/non-prod top-level folders and prod/non-prod app lifecycle folders in enterprise organization structure (on GCP)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, organization

I am trying to organize an enterprise's organization via Terraform, by implementing good IaC practices. In [this article](https://medium.com/@wynsen/gcp-folder-hierarchy-group-management-with-terraform-3a870cd5357e) the author suggests an organization structure that will have the following top-level folders

> Top-level Folders
>
> Consider a solution where the Top-level Folders are:
>
> Sandpit
>
> Non-Production
>
> Production
>
> Shared
>
> Subsidiary

But also leaf-level folders to contain larger or smaller apps that will also be defined with several folders for each environment (dev, prod, etc...)

> Leaf Folders
>
> ...
>
> Large applications where multiple squads with different access
> requirements are responsible for different components of the software
> development life-cycle may warrant a Folder each for Development, SIT,
> UAT, Staging & Production. The name of these Folders could contain
> both the application & life-cycle.

These distinctions appear in several other repos and ways to organize enterprise-level infrastructure.

Could you provide an explanation on what warrants such a distinction between top-level and leaf-level prod/non-prod folders? Is there a use-case where we use them simultaneously?

Comment: At a given point in its development, Terraform supported workspaces and modules. You would want to use those instead of the former custom solutions.

Comment: @MattSchuchard, If I understand the article correctly, modules are used in tandem with these architectures. Also, workspaces seem to exist to manage separate groups of resources that can be used from the same directory... Here I'm just trying to understand why enterprise-structures within GCP can have prod/non-prod folders at both top-level but also within at the app lifecycle-level...

Comment: This former custom solution for organization is independent of cloud provider platform. It applied to any, and not just GCP.

Comment: @MattSchuchard yes of course. The article in question if for GCP, but the enterprise organization is agnostic.